# Getting unknown exception while contacting Google Cloud Api through a Proxy Server

Tags: java, proxy, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

Sitting behind the Proxy Server of my corporate, i have difficulties, accessing the Google Speech API.

My code is the following (copied and modified from a sample from google):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "x.x.x.x");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "xxxx");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "x.x.x.x");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "xxxx");

FileInputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Path\\To\\Credentials.json");
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
FixedCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);

SpeechSettings speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings)) {
    RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding encoding = RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16;
    int sampleRateHertz = 16000;
    String languageCode = "de-DE";
    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setEncoding(encoding)
            .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRateHertz).setLanguageCode(languageCode).build();
    String uri = "C:\\recordings\\testRec16hz.wav";
    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(uri).build();

    RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.setException(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:118)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:101)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:392)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:475)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:478)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:590)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:83)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.connect(SocketUtils.java:80)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:254)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1291)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:298)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.connect(ProxyHandler.java:181)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.connect(SslHandler.java:674)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.connect(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:459)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler.connect(ProtocolNegotiators.java:458)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler.connect(ProtocolNegotiators.java:458)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$11.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:535)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
```

I think the response might be directed from the proxy server and therefore not readable by the google sdk.

When I run without setting the proxy-properties, i get the following after a while:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded: -115304848173 ns from now
```

How can I read the Response to further information? 
How do I proceed - do I need to contact the admin of the proxy server?

Comment: I am getting the same exact two errors.  Only difference is that I am using the PubSub java client library.

Comment: They are both definitely related to proxy.  I placed my jar file on the cloud platform and executed it flawlessly from there with 0 errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At least i am not alone. I will post here as soon as I find a solution.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. see [here on git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1061)